# How do you solve for x algebraically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$$x^{\log2 / \log3} = x^{1/2} + 1$$

Using desmos, I figured out that the answer is 9. But is there a way to solve algebraically??

Comment: Perhaps useful: $x^{\frac{\log 2}{\log 3}} = e^{\frac{\log 2}{\log 3}\log x} = 2^{\frac{\log x}{\log 3}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^{\frac{\log2} {\log3}} = x^{\frac12} + 1$$
Let $y=x^{\frac12}$,
$$y^{\frac{2\log2} {\log3}} = y + 1$$
$$\frac{2\log2} {\log3}\log y =\log \left( y + 1\right)$$
$${\log y}\cdot\log 4 =\log 3 \cdot\log \left( y + 1\right)$$

Compare two sides,
$$\therefore y= 3,x=y^2=9.$$

Comment: "Compare two sides": why does $\ln y\ln 4=\ln 3\ln(y+1)$ imply that $y=3$? Why is there not a second, say, trascendental solution?

Comment: I just saw this comment but you are right. How can we know? Is there a way to prove that x=9 is the only solution?

Comment: We can show $f(y)=\log 4\log y-\log 3\log (y+1)$ is increasing on $(1,+\infty)$ by taking the derivative $f'(y)=\dfrac{\log 4}{y}-\dfrac{\log 3}{y+1}>0$.

Answer (score 0):

$x=9$ is the only solution because $x=9$ is the only intersection between $x$ and $1-2x^k+x^{2k}$, where $k=\frac{log2}{log3}$.